Bad guy tied to a chair, grenade explodes in his mouth
I really don't have much more information about this, but I feel it won't be that hard for you to find this movie.
I've seen it as a kid on cable TV in the mid 90's in Argentina (but I think it's a typical Hollywood action movie), so it can be anything between the 60's and, say, '95.
It was an action movie - some huge, badass hero, Rambo style or something like that - that was fighting don't-know-who, and the final scene was the only thing I remember.
They were at some place that looks like an island or something - a beach, or an open field like that -, and somehow the bad guy was tied to a chair, already defeated, and he has a grenade on his mouth - presumably put there by the hero -, so the movie's last scene is a "great"* take of his head exploding.
I've just found Wanted Dead or Alive, but I feel it's not that one - I don't remember the scene to be as dark, and the hero was more of a rude, muscle, shirt off guy.
* For what a 6 years-old's definition of "great" may be

Your description matches a lot Wanted Dead or Alive, are you sure it's not it?

It may me doubt myself, but I'm really confident about the scene not being so dark - something like a tiny island, I don't know why I keep thinking about that -, and the hero being a Rambo/Conan/something like that.

@mgarciaisaia Though he's not tied to a chair in the 1987 film Strike Commando the Rambo looking hero puts a grenade in the bad guys mouth right at the end of the movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwGDyDL4fiM. If it's the one I will put it as an answer

I'd +1 this answer - it fits the description too well -, but I still think it's not it. Thanks, @tohood87
